# JSLint Object Error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am using JSLint to lint the following code:

```
'use strict';

var mathService = {
   add: add,
   subtract: subtract,
   multiply: multiply,
   divide: divide,
   power: power,
   squareRoot: squareRoot
};

function add(first, second) {
   return first + second;
}

function subtract(first, second) {
   return first - second;
}

function multiply(first, second) {
   return first * second;
}

function divide(first, second) {
   return first / second;
}

function power(first, second) {
   return Math.pow(first, second);
}

function squareRoot(first) {
   return Math.sqrt(first);
}
```

When I try to lint this code, I get an error message for each property in my object indicating that it is undefined. However, I did not think one had to define object properties? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the exact error message? I assume it's complaining that the functions are assigned before they are defined.

Comment: Note that the error is referring to the items to the _right_ of the colons in your object definition - the property names themselves are fine.  You can see this if you change either the property or function names so they are different - the errors refer to the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Fortunately, Clyde Lobo's code did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Move the object after the functions, like

```
"use strict";

function add(first, second) {
   return first + second;
}

function subtract(first, second) {
   return first - second;
}

function multiply(first, second) {
   return first * second;
}

function divide(first, second) {
   return first / second;
}

function power(first, second) {
   return Math.pow(first, second);
}

function squareRoot(first) {
   return Math.sqrt(first);
}

var mathService = {
   add: add,
   subtract: subtract,
   multiply: multiply,
   divide: divide,
   power: power,
   squareRoot: squareRoot
};
```

You would get some warnings, but no error.